# How to launch an activity when notification is clicked?

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications

I have a strange problem in my app in android. I have done a notification and I want to launch a new activity when notification is clicked. The problems is that when I click on notification nothing happens, and I have no idea where is the problem? Can anyone help me?Here is my code :

```
notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
CharSequence NotificationTicket = "Notification";
CharSequence NotificationTitle = "Notification";
CharSequence NotificationContent = "Test";
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
NotificationTicket, when);

Context context = getApplicationContext();

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, ShopsOnMap.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
notificationIntent, 0);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, NotificationTitle, NotificationContent, contentIntent); 
notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Comment: Just a tip: the bar with buttons on top lets you format code easily (use the `{}` buttons for instance).

Comment: I see no problem, you might want to add some debugging `Log.d` code to your ShopsOnMap activity's oncreate, to see if the problem might be there?

Comment: I do not understand what you meant to say.Can you be more explicit?Or can you give me an example plss

Comment: in LogCat I have :"05-14 11:40:35.858: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.ShoppingList/.ShopsOnMap bnds=[0,101][320,165] }
"

Comment: Well, I'm assuming you have an activity `ShopsOnMap`, as you are calling that. You say "nothing happens", but I'm suggesting that something does happen, but another problem in that class makes it not start. A missing bundle (`extra`) in the intent for instance. So you should open the ShopsOnMap.java file, find the `onCreate` function, and add a `Log.d()` call. Then read the logfile and see if it is runningn or not.

Comment: ah. our comments crossed. It looks like the intent is called. So the problem is in the `shopsonmap` class probably? how would you normally start that app? with that class?

Comment: I don't get any error..so, I don't know where is the problem. In class ShopsOnMap I have only this : public class ShopsOnMap extends Activity{

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
}

Comment: I want that when notification is clicked,the class ShopsOnMap to start. I don't use this class in other classes.Can you have an example that works and launch a new activity? This can help me a lot.

Comment: Sure. But it looks really like yours. I'll add something

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem and then realized that I hadn't declared my new activity in the Manifest.

```
<activity
        android:name=".YourActivityHere">
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 3):

you need set action  and category for Intent.

if this activity isn't the entry point of the application:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ShopsOnMap.class);
notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

PendingIntent myIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

and if is the entry point of your application, you have it by xml,  like it:

```
<activity
        android:name=".ShopsOnMap"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
          android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

so, so, only need add it:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ShopsOnMap.class);
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

PendingIntent myIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Now i know this question is VERY old, but for me a solution was to change the requestCode. Apparently it doesn't work sometimes when the requestCode is 0. It worked for me on one phone but didn't work on the other.

Answer (score 0):

As in the comments: I can't see anything wrong with your code, and suspect your `shopsonmap` to just not show anything. Below code that I use and that works.

```
private void setNotifiy(){
    String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);

    int icon = R.drawable.notification_icon;//  R.drawable.notification_icon;
    CharSequence tickerText = "Tickertext goes here :) !";
    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence contentTitle = "ThisIsYourTitle";
    CharSequence contentText = "some content goes here";

    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MyClass.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);    
    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOT_ID, notification);
}
```

Comment: I found that the problem is my class ShopsOnMap. I tried with an other class and it works. But I have now a new problem. If I create a new class for using in this case I get the error NoClassDefFound...I have been search a lot for a solution but I did'nt find nothing for help me. Do you know a solution for this error?

Comment: Did you put it in your manifest? Maybe mark this as answered, and start another question with some code (the class, the call and your manifest?)